# JSON Android Error parsing data

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-webservice

please I have problem with my JSON webservice. When I call function , I am getting this exception:

```
03-19 15:14:10.013: E/JSON Parser(12011): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:223)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at dp.zajac.facerecognizer3.FromCameraMainSceneFragment.uploadFaceToServer(FromCameraMainSceneFragment.java:657)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at dp.zajac.facerecognizer3.FromCameraMainSceneFragment.onSingleFaceDialogPositiveClickWithDatabases(FromCameraMainSceneFragment.java:635)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at dp.zajac.savefacesdialogs.FaceToSaveDialog$3.onClick(FaceToSaveDialog.java:162)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/System.err(12011):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4830)
03-19 15:14:10.013: W/dalvikvm(12011): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416742a0)
03-19 15:14:10.023: W/System.err(12011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:14:10.023: W/System.err(12011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 15:14:10.023: W/System.err(12011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
03-19 15:14:10.023: W/System.err(12011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
03-19 15:14:10.023: W/System.err(12011):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 15:14:10.033: W/System.err(12011): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:14:10.033: W/System.err(12011):    at dp.fedorko.client.jsonClient.doInBackground(jsonClient.java:58)
03-19 15:14:10.033: W/System.err(12011):    at dp.fedorko.client.jsonClient.doInBackground(jsonClient.java:1)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-19 15:14:10.043: W/System.err(12011):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I use this code for calling **JSON web service**:

```
 protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if((Integer)params[0]==0)
            return null;
        if((Integer)params[0]==1){
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "mobilefirst"));
            //params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vector", "0 1 2 1 0"));
            //params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("personid", "1"));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params1);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            return json.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And this is **jsonParser** code:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Here is my **web service code**:

```
<?php
 //require_once __DIR__ . '/php_connect.php';
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) /* && isset($_POST['vector']) && isset($_POST['personid'])*/) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    //$vector = $_POST['vector'];
    //$personid = $_POST['personid'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/php_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES('$name')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Please where can be problem? I am stuck on this. I do not see where is the problem.

Thank you for every answer.

Martin

Comment: use `sb.append(line);` instead of `sb.append(line + "\n");` also log json before converting to JSONObject for check getting valid json string from server or not

Comment: How can I log this json?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK How can I log this Json?

Comment: just add  `Log.e("Buffer Error", "json response " + json);` before converting to JSONObject

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am not sure where to place this code...

Comment: when I place it before converting, in LogCat I get 03-19 19:56:59.673: E/Buffer Error(18389): json response 
03-19 19:56:59.673: E/JSON Parser(18389): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of  .....

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I correct some things and now I get this: 03-19 21:31:40.083: E/Buffer Error(20317): json response <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1><p>You don't have permission to access /webservicerecognitionjson/php_upload.phpon this server.</p></body></html>
What can be problem?

Comment: as logcat output you are not getting valid json string from server with error message `You don't have permission to access /webservicerecognitionjson/php_upload.phpon this server.` so check your webservice is running from from browser or using any other HTTP tool before accessing in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data in not complete or not properly formatted. Validate first before you construct. Don't trust the source.

Comment: what does it mean? where can be problem ?

Comment: @MartinFedyFedorko The json data you are receiving is invalid or corrupt.